# How do I let an executing azure function complete during a shut down?

Tags: azure-functions

Active functions are killed when a Function App is restarted which includes restarts, stop/starts, publishing on top, and swapping deployment slots.  For a functions that are run frequently, that's a problem.

We are sticking with the goal of our functions to be very fast running.  Maybe a few seconds at most.

But, when a Function App is stopped or restarted, the host is not providing the "actively running" functions a chance to complete before stopping.  This means we're going to have to manage the state of every function execution which defeats the purpose of stateless, fast-running functions.  And to make it worse, managing that state (like writing it to a store of some kind) is not guaranteed to complete either.

Is there any way to either configure the Function App to NOT do this (and wait X seconds before forceably cancelling the function executions)?  If not, is there a way to hook into the shutdown process and make it "wait" while active functions complete?

The `CancellationToken` is great for triggering something to run for static cleanup (like flushing logs) but when it runs the active functions have already been cancelled.

I created a simple repro with instructions on setup and posted it to GitHub:
https://github.com/retsvek/UngracefulUnloadOfFunctions

Answer (score 2):

Functions runtime is built for a graceful shutdown when the Function Host gets restarted. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/661e8de8449865139d20fe019f789a65cfe5da33/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHostManager.cs#L160). Also, [updating the function code does not restart the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853352/detecting-update-redeployment-inside-running-azure-function). Please note that when w3wp process gets restarted - happens when FunctionApp is restarted it does [kill running instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935118/stop-kill-a-running-azure-function). Also, when using [deployment slots](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/13/deployment-slots-preview-for-azure-functions/), does restart the worker process. Deployment slots are not intended for maintaining running function instances.

Functions running on consumption plan have a default timeout set to 5 minutes. If functions run past the default timeout, there is no guarantee of completing function execution. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) is a way to extend default timeout to 10 minutes.

Please see [Functions Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices) for guidance on implementing functions.

We now have a preview feature [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview) that is intended for stateful coordination problems - Hope this helps your scenario.

Comment: Can you comment on why someone would have responded on this SO question that it SHOULD be waiting gracefully for functions to finish?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071193/azure-function-deployment-kill-my-running-process-can-i-avoid

Originally I was not doing async with awaits (I was doing everything with synchronous calls) but I switched to async/await and it shows the same behavior (is cancelling the active functions).  Thanks!

Comment: Behavior mentioned in the (SO thread)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071193/azure-function-deployment-kill-my-running-process-can-i-avoid] is still valid. I was specifically referring to configuring a timeout setting before functions host shuts down. Can you please share simple repro code for the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I can provide a sample but it will require setting up an Azure Service Bus queue (for the trigger) as well as an Azure SQL DB to show the behavior.  Let me know if you're still interested and I'll put it together.  The pseudo code is (A) receive message from bus via trigger (B) write entry to SQL (C) sleep for 5 seconds (D) write second entry to SQL.  When you get it going so there are enough messages so that functions are ALWAYS running, when you STOP, then START the function, you'll see too many entries in SQL (because it killed the function, put the message back on the bus, and reprocessed)

Comment: And if you believe it works correctly and the only thing missing is "configuring a timeout," then what is the current timeout being used?  All my function does is sleep for 5 seconds.  Perhaps that already exceeds the timeout?

Comment: I have updated the answer with information related to default timeouts. Please go ahead and share your code and also any errors you see in your logs.

Comment: Pragna - I have to disagree with your statement that the runtime "already accounts" for graceful shutdown.  It's entirely possible I'm doing something wrong, but I added a repro link to GitHub in my initial question that shows you the behavior that I'm talking about.  I would expect the "in flight" executions to finish which would result in no messages needing to be reprocessed.  Give it a look and let me know what you think.  And thank you!!

Comment: Looked through your code and repro steps. The behavior you are seeing is expected as you are restarting the Function App. I have updated my answer to clarify difference between restarting Functions Host vs restarting App itself. Hope this helps!

Comment: So what I'm gleaning from this answer is that the ONLY way to get the support for graceful shutdown is to use the paradigm where you host your source code within the function app instead of deploying a pre-compiled function app from, say, Visual Studio.  If that is correct, then this finally clarifies "graceful shutdowns" and that it only works in that particular use case.  Will it ever be supported for pre-compiled function apps?  And thank you very much for looking through the repro so we could get to this clarity. :)